# Как создать программу, которая при нажатии кнопки"старт" записывает, какие сайты посетил пользователь и сколько времени провел на них?

Tags: java, c#

Ну собственно все в заголовке вопроса. Мне не нужен код, хотелось бы услышать совет, куда копать. Хотелось бы, чтобы решалось на c# или java

Comment: для какого то конкретного браузера или для любого?

Comment: в идеале для лобого

Comment: вам как минимум понадобится прокси-сервер и сниффер, использующий MITM

Comment: вот [эта штука](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddlercore) работает как сниффер и перехватывает траффик. Я бы поглядел в её сторону, коди писал бы на C#